# JavaFX ListView keyboard navigability

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am quite satisfied with the GUI elements of JavaFX; however, the [ListView control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) offers no alphanumeric keyboard navigability by default. The arrow keys work, but jumping to items beginning with "a" by typing the respective letter key does not.

Is this feature built-in? If not, how would you implement it?

Comment: It's not built-in. It's quite difficult to see how it could be built into the general case: you're presumably referring to the text displayed in the cells beginning with the letter from the keystroke, and in general that text is not in memory for all items in the list (because of cell reuse). (And in the general case, cells may not even display text but might use a graphic, etc etc).

Comment: Thanks, yes, this  makes sense and was my first assumption. It's probably due to my coming from other (non-Java) GUI toolkits, where you get the beavior out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I implemented it this way:

```java
private String searchText = "";
private long searchTextLastTyped = 0;
private int searchTextSkip = 0;
```

...

```java
listView.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getCharacter() != null) {
            //in case of same character typed more times = search next occurence
            if (searchText.equals(event.getCharacter())) {
                searchTextSkip++;
            } else {
                //in case typing more characters relatively quickly = append character
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - searchTextLastTyped < 1000) {
                    searchText += event.getCharacter();
                //typing new character after pause = new search
                } else {
                    searchText = event.getCharacter();
                }
            }
            searchTextLastTyped = System.currentTimeMillis();

            boolean found = false;
            int skipped = 0;
            for (T item : getItems()) {
                if (getTextValue(item).toUpperCase().startsWith(searchText.toUpperCase())) {
                    if (searchTextSkip > skipped) {
                        skipped++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    setValue(item);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //reset to first occurence
            if (!found) {
                searchTextSkip = 0;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

Here's a class that can be dropped in, which has a few minor tweaks to the code above:

```java
private static final class ListViewHandler<T> {
  /**
   * Amount of time to wait between key presses that typing a subsequent
   * key is considered part of the same search, in milliseconds.
   */
  private static final int RESET_DELAY_MS = 1250;

  private String mNeedle = "";
  private int mSearchSkip = 0;
  private long mLastTyped = currentTimeMillis();
  private final ListView<T> mHaystack;

  private ListViewHandler( final ListView<T> listView ) {
    mHaystack = listView;
  }

  private void handle( final KeyEvent key ) {
    var ch = key.getText();

    if( ch == null || ch.isEmpty() ||
      key.getCode() == ESCAPE || key.getCode() == ENTER ) {
      return;
    }

    ch = ch.toUpperCase();

    if( mNeedle.equals( ch ) ) {
      mSearchSkip++;
    }
    else {
      mNeedle = currentTimeMillis() - mLastTyped > RESET_DELAY_MS
        ? ch : mNeedle + ch;
    }

    mLastTyped = currentTimeMillis();

    boolean found = false;
    int skipped = 0;
    for( final T item : mHaystack.getItems() ) {
      final var straw = item.toString().toUpperCase();

      if( straw.startsWith( mNeedle ) ) {
        if( mSearchSkip > skipped ) {
          skipped++;
          continue;
        }

        mHaystack.getSelectionModel().select( item );
        final int index = mHaystack.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        mHaystack.getFocusModel().focus( index );
        mHaystack.scrollTo( index );
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if( !found ) {
      mSearchSkip = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```java
final var listView = // ... get the ListView object;
final var handler = new ListViewHandler<>( listView );
listView.setOnKeyTyped( handler::handle );
```